# Какую роль в художественном произведении играет смешение стилей?

Tags: стилистика, поэзия

Смешение стилей  в качестве художественного приема использовал **А. С. Пушкин**, например:

*Зима!.. Крестьянин, торжествуя,*

*На дровнях обновляет путь;*

*Его лошадка, снег почуя,*

*Плетется рысью как-нибудь;*

Мы видим, что даже в  небольшом по объему отрывке автор использует слова **книжного, высокого и просторечного** стилей.

А вот **романтизм,** с моей точки зрения,  в этом отношении **однообразен** и поэтому немного скучен, излишнее количество  красивого и высокого тоже утомляет.

Так ли это, нужно ли это учитывать в творчестве или при анализе произведений? Можно ли найти подобные примеры в современной литературе?

Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Однако смешение стилей **может быть ошибочным**,  как говорится, например, в статье «Винегрет стилей: почему это не съедобно».
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/liteditor59/vinegret-stilei-pochemu-eto-ne-sedobno-5d89118335c8d800b2d12eb8

Но здесь необходимо **тонкое искусство**, не всякому писателю оно доступно. Так что не  нужны тут крайности: не надо всё возводить в абсолют, но и не надо  мазать черной краской.   К примеру, неправильное смешение стилей может иметь **иронический** смысл.

Да дело не только в стилях – **однообразие утомляет во всем** (и в искусстве, и в жизни).  А писателям уж точно не мешает время от времени «переодеваться». В этом отношении интересна книга М. Цветаевой «Мой Пушкин», где говорится о разной смысловой нагрузке стихотворных строк у Пушкина  – они как бы делятся на фон и основное содержание. Тоже своеобразная ритмика.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Праздный вопрос?** Возможно и так, да не очень-то я и рассчитываю на ответы. Но все-таки объясню, почему говорю на эту тему.

**Люди сейчас пишут очень много**.  Иногда и хочется что-то почитать из современной поэзии, тогда я просматриваю список произведений. Названия обычно такие красивые, но читаю  сами стихи не часто – надо делать это  со смыслом, чтобы польза была, а времени и душевных сил решительно не хватает.

**Иногда все-таки бывают исключения** (по разным причинам), но  вот что интересно. Часто стихи выглядят  вполне корректно по форме и содержанию, но они не нравятся мне по причине **однообразия.** Один и тот же стиль, одна и та же тема повторяется бесконечно, так что **уж нового и сказать поэту нечего**.
Такое однообразие утомляет, и я закрываю страницу.